# Elasticity/Flexibility to Robots

Tags: control, ros, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, Is there any way to simulate provide the elastic property of the links?. I am trying to simulate Ornithopter(a robotic bird). The problem is that the wing has to be flexible and elastic to create vortices. But, I can't find a way to do that. Is it possible?.
(Please give me any example package which implements flexible property)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247449/elasticity/flexibility-to-robots/) by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'd have to break the wing into a number of rigid body elements with joints between them to approximate the flexible and elastic properties.  The joint properties plus actuator controllers property tuned could do the physics, or a separate model of a wing could generate the position of every rigid body and the actuators would be driven to try to match that.

Other than that I'm working on a simulation package that wraps the bullet physics engine: https://github.com/lucasw/simple_sim_ros, bullet supports soft bodies and I'll add support for those eventually.  Try out the bullet demo applications and see if the soft bodies might work for you, there are volumetric kinds (with internal 'struts') and others which are more like balloons (only a surface, which is easier to import from a mesh).

**Update**

simple_sim_ros main branch now supports bullet soft bodies

Also there is work towards support in gazebo: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1422/soft-body-supoort-in-gazebo

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on 2016-11-23**:
Thank you, Lucas, for your detailed answer. As of now, I created the ornithopter model with stiff wings. Then, I applied lift-drag plugin to its control surfaces(wings and tail). The ornithopter is able to lift but not good. Now, I started working on bullet engine. I Will update the results.